# React Navigation: receiving 'undefined' with this.props.navigation.state.params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a strange problem when I am passing props down to another screen.

I am passing two parameters; `title` and `body`, to ArticleBody screen.

```
class ListButtonWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.articleSelected = this.articleSelected.bind(this);
  }

  articleSelected() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ArticleBody', {
      title: this.props.title,
      body: this.props.body
    });
  }
```

When the button is pressed, it should pass those props to the next screen. And it does!

```
class ArticleBody extends React.Component {
render() {

    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const { title } = params ? params.title : null;
    const { body } = params ? params.body : null;
    console.log(title, body, params.title, params.body);
    return (
      <View>
      <Text>Title: {title}</Text>
      <Text>Body: {body}</Text>
      </View>
    );
```

However, calling `{title}` or `{body}` in `<Text>` doesn't show anything. Using console.log reveals that {title} and {body} are *undefined*.

However! If I use `params.title` or `params.body`, both show up as they should. But, according to the documentation, calling `title` or `body` should work.

But, here's another problem. If I change `const { title } = params ? params.title : null;` to `const { title } = params.title` it *still* shows up as undefined when I call `title`

I'm stumped. So far I can call `params.title` or `params.body` directly, but it should be working in the defined variables as well, right?

What am I doing wrong?

*UPDATE*

Want to add a little update. If I console.log `this.props.navigation.state`, I see that the props are being passed down to ArticleBody. Here is the log:

```
{params: {…}, key: "id-1519274761934-2", routeName: "ArticleBody"}
key: "id-1519274761934-2"
params:
  body:"more stuff"
  title:"stuff"
__proto__
Object
routeName:"ArticleBody"
__proto__
Object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with your code

```
const { title } = params ? params.title : null;
const { body } = params ? params.body : null;
```

The ternary condition is deciding which object you're trying to do a destructuring assignment on. In your case it's either the `params.title` or `params.body`. So your actually becomes

```
title = params.title.title
body = param.body.body
```

You should either use

```
const { title, body } = params ? params: null;
```

or

```
const title = params ? params.title: null;
const body = params ? params.body : null;
```

Comment: @Nathan To clarify, the ternary condition is deciding which object you're trying to do a destructuring assignment on. In your case it's either the `params.title`/`params.body` object or null.

Comment: This is me banging my head against the desk right now...

Thank's mate, I appreciate the help! Ugh I feel dumb. haha

Comment: @HenrikAndersson, thanks! Updated your comment in the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

use props.route instead of props.navigation

Answer (score 1):

If using react-navigation v5 "getParam" is deprecated, so
the same thing can be achieved using the optional chaining and nullish coalescing operators:

```
const data = navigation.getParam('someParam', 'defaultValue');
```

is equivalent to:

```
const data = route.params?.someParam ?? 'defaultValue';
```