# React Navigation - this.props.navigation.state is undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

Using:
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.4.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.4",

App.js:

```js
    import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    ...
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    const DrawerRender = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} options={{unmountOnBlur: true, gestureEnabled: false}} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} options={{unmountOnBlur: true, gestureEnabled: false}} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );}
```

From Screen1:

```js
    navigateToPage = page_id => {
      this.closeCommentScreen();
      this.reopenModal = true;
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {'page_id': 'testing'});
    }
```

On Screen2:

```js
    export default class Screen2 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
       let id = this.props.navigation.state.params.page_id
       ...
```

I tried printing "this.props.navigation" and it always returns empty dictionary {}, hence params is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems same like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919803/react-navigation-receiving-undefined-with-this-props-navigation-state-params)

Comment: my this.props.navigation is empty. state.params will always be null

Comment: It does not work on both screens?

Comment: navigation.navigate works with no issue. When I try to access the params from Screen2, it errors out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `this.props.route.params`

See the upgrade guide https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x#separate-route-prop

Answer (score 0):

first Screen

```
nav.setOptions({
                        headerRight: () => <Button
                            title='Add coin'
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Crypto Information', {
                                params: { currentCoins: temp },
                            })}
                        >
                        </Button>,
                    });
```

Second Screen

```
const CryptoInformation = ({ _, route }) => {
const { params } = route.params
```