# Sending params with navigation.goBack in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

hellow , how to send params navigation go back ?

```
const Onsubmit = (data, details = null) => {
    console.log(details.formatted_address);
    route.params.onPlaceChosen(
      route.params.id,
      details.formatted_address,
      details.geometry
    );
    navigation.goBack();
  };
```

here I want to pass the value from details.formatted_address to page B.
How to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are navigating from Screen A to Screen B, and when you want to go back to Screen A with running a callback in again Screen A, below is what you need to do:

In your Screen A (Source)

```
...
const onPlaceChosen = (params) => {
    // here is your callback function
}

...
navigation.navigate('ScreenB', { onPlaceChosen })
...
```

In your Screen B (Destination)

```
..
const Onsubmit = (data, details = null) => {

    navigation.state.params.onPlaceChosen(
      route.params.id,
      details.formatted_address,
      details.geometry
    );
    navigation.goBack();
  };
...
```

Comment: Got warning when passing function as parrams.

Comment: navigation.state is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's `this.props.route.params`.  Answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61261000

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/troubleshooting/#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state

Answer (score 1):

I did this way:

```
onPress={() => {
    // Pass and merge params back to home screen
    navigation.navigate({
        name: 'Home',
        params: { post: postText },
        merge: true,
    });
}}
```

It was extracted from:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this based on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props

```
const [params, setParams] = useState({});   

<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="One">
  {props => <FirstScreen {...props} paramsFromTwo={params} />}
  </Stack.Screen>  

  <Stack.Screen name="Two">
  {props => <SecondScreen {...props} onGoBack={(paramsFromSecond} => setParams(paramsFromSecond)} />}
  </Stack.Screen>  
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, using navigation and route passed by props, the solution was:

```
route.params.onFilter({
    route.params.id,
    details.formatted_address,
    details.geometry
});
navigation.goBack();
```